# Getting Blank instead of a value when using -> in PHP

Tags: php

I am making a web app. In one part of it, I have JS send a JSON string to PHP. The conent of the string is:

```
{"date":"24-03-2014","Cars":["Cheap","Expensive"]}
```

I want to convert the string into an object, for which I am doing:

```
$meta = $_POST["meta"];
$obj = json_decode($meta);
echo $obj->date;
```

Anyhow, Instead of having `24-03-2014` as the output, I am getting a blank line as the output.

What's wrong? What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: It works well, check if $_POST data is in correct format as u specified.

Comment: Step one: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393)

Comment: Is error reporting on? What does `$meta` contain? What does `$obj` contain?

Comment: It work for me. Are you sure that you have JSON in `meta` parameter?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['meta']);` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Not able to re-produce it:

```
$jsonStr = '{"date":"24-03-2014","Cars":["Cheap","Expensive"]}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

var_dump($jsonObj);
var_dump($jsonObj->date);
```

Outputs:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'date' => string '24-03-2014' (length=10)
  public 'Cars' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Cheap' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Expensive' (length=9)

string '24-03-2014' (length=10)
```

Are you sure your `$_POST['meta']` is set & has values?

Comment: This should really be a (shorter) comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below works like a charm. Your $_POST["date"] has not correct value inside. Try var_dump($_POST) to debug it.

```
<?php
  $input = '{"date":"24-03-2014","Cars":["Cheap","Expensive"]}';
  $meta = $input;
  $obj = json_decode($meta);
  var_dump($obj->date); //Prints string(10) "24-03-2014"
?>
```

Comment: Again, should be a comment.